# Django: How to write a function based view used for URL with parameter

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am learning Django, using function based views, and I am struggling with the following:
I have this path in urls.py

```
path('user/<str:username>',views.UserProjectList,name='user-projects')
```

that is supposed to show all the projects of the particular user (client). In order to reach it, username should be parameter of the function based view, however I am struggling how to write such view...
I have this:

```
def UserProjectList(request,username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username) #THIS IS WRONG and should return id of the user
    #user = User.objects.filter(username=username) #also wrong

    tag_list = ProjectTagsSQL.objects.all() #ProjectTagsSQL and ProjectSQL are connected
    project_list = ProjectSQL.objects.filter(client=user) #ProjectSQL table has column client_id (pk is id in User) and table contains all the projects

    context = {
        'tagy' : tag_list,
        'projecty' : project_list
    }

    return render(request, 'home_page/user_projects.html', context) #SHOULD THE PARAMETER BE INCLUDED HERE?
```

I tried to inspire with the code from class based view I found on the internets (thats is working for me but i didnt manage to connect it with ProjectTagsSQL as i managed in FBV, but that's a different problem) but i didnt manage

```
class UserProjectListView(ListView):
    model = ProjectSQL
    template_name = 'home_page/user_projects.html' 
    context_object_name = 'data'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return ProjectSQL.objects.filter(client=user)
```

Could someone help me how to deal with such function based view please? As this solution its not working (will return nothing for any user)

Here is also the ProjectSQL model (and ProjectTagsSQL model) :

```
class ProjectSQL(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    country = models.TextField()
    city = models.TextField()
    time_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    client = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = False #https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/
        db_table = 'project'

class ProjectTagsSQL(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(ProjectSQL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(ProjectTagSQL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = False  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/
        db_table = 'project_tags'
```

Comment: Do you want to return `user` in function based view, what's exactly the problem, it isn't clear.

Comment: The result should be that the view is returning the list of projects of particular user (page home_page/user/user1234 would show projects of user1234), but the code in the question doesnt return anything for any user, unlike the one written with class based view (but that one is missing info about projects from different connected model). hope its more clear now :)

Comment: Can you show `ProjectSQL` model? And also I don't the class based view is correct, since how can you return three things in `get_queryset()` method. If you want three things which are `user` instance, and other two querysets, so you should use `get_context_data()` method instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right with the class based view. I left there other returns that shouldnt be there. I am updating the problem desc. I am also adding there the ProjectSQL model

Comment: Just do `ProjectSQL.objects.filter(client=user.id)` instead, see below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write `user.id` so:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def UserProjectList(request,username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User,username=username)
    tag_list = ProjectTagsSQL.objects.all()
    project_list = ProjectSQL.objects.filter(client=user.id)

    context = {
        'tagy' : tag_list,
        'projecty' : project_list
    }

    return render(request, 'home_page/user_projects.html', context)
```

Also, try to check template variables' name, whether you used same or not.

> **Note:** Always append `/` at the end of every route so it should be `path('user/<str:username>/'...`.

> **Note:** Function based views are generally written in `snake_case` so it is better to name it as `user_project_list` instead of `UserProjectList`.

Comment: I updated this way, and unfortunatelly it's still not working :( I mean, it still doesnt show any projects of the user, the same result as before

Comment: @rebro Can you please share your template too? Does the class based view work perfectly?

Comment: @rebro Did you get any error?

Comment: aaaah that's where i had mistake! i didnt refer to 'projecty'.... now its working, thank you very much Sunderam!

Comment: I left there the old name 'data' that i was using with class based view...

Comment: @rebro Ah, that happens several times, that's why I asked to share template :)